# c# Adding web functionality to a windows forms project

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms, web

I am running a windows forms application on a server which do many things. My intention is to get some web functionality to the application, for example view the logfile in a browser or manipulate the Settings.Defaults via browser.

Is it possible to add the web functionality to a winforms application ?

Comment: What do you mean by `view the logfile in a browser` using a winform application?

Comment: You can use `WebBrowserContorl` in windows forms.

Comment: <h2>to get some web functionality to the application</h2><br/>I think you need to explain more about that however you can search for http listener but instead of it i rather suggest you to build a web application which could share content coming from your winform app.

Comment: No WebBrowserControl is for using a Webbrowser in a windows form, what i mean is to access the winform app from a browser outside the server. For example I contact via browser from a client pc the url http://servername/winformapp.aspx or something to get the mentioned features. @Shaharyar: On this page I would see what the app on the server is doing. At the moment it writes to a local textfile.

Comment: You will have to make a `web service` which will read that file and return the data to you. You can also achieve it by making a simple `webform` and throw data using `Response.Write`. But web service is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by self hosting web API into your windows form application like demonstrated [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/older-versions/self-host-a-web-api)

The second option is to use [ASP.NET 5 self-hosting](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting) but it is still in beta and has no good documentation yet.

**Edit 1:**
To support viewing pages using Web API 2 you need to follow the following steps:
First, let JSON formatter handle HTML requests like the following

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  "API Default", "api/{controller}/{id}",
  new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

// Add the supported media type.            
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Second, Save the desired html template files on disk with placeholders that will be replaced with your actual data at runtime and change the controller like below

```
    public String GetAllProducts()
    {
        //Should be loaded from HTML template file ex. Products.html
        string html = "<html><body><table border=\"2\"><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th><tr>{{placeholder}}</table></body></html>";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + item.Id + "</td><td>" + item.Name + "</td><td>" + item.Category + "</td><td>" + item.Price + "</td></tr>");
        }
        return html.Replace("{{placeholder}}", sb.ToString());
    }
```

**Note:** If you don't like the default JSON formatter you can write your own like there did tn [this project](https://github.com/WebApiContrib)

Comment: The link sounds interesting I will have a look at that.

Comment: Hi, the link helps me much, bit I used the owin method. I'm now able to get   for example the Setting.Default.sourcepath value by http://localhost:9000/api/settings. But how give I the app a web interface ? I mean, going to http://localhost:9000/index.aspx (or html?) where I define all my Settings for example which post it to my api ?